# fuzzy search in supabase

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

IS there a way we can do fuzzy matching in Supabase Table.
I am looking to find match between words like "cherly" and "cher!y".
I tried fts, plfts, phfts and wfts but none of them do partial matching.

Is there a way to do fuzzy matching in Supabase?

Answer (score 0):

Check out these extensions:

- fuzzystrmatch (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/fuzzystrmatch.html)
- pg_trgm (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html)

In your case you might want the levenshtein function (fuzzystrmatch) which would detect that there is only 1 character difference

```sql
SELECT levenshtein('cherly', 'cher!y');
```

result

```markdown
| levenshtein |
| ----------- |
| 1           |
```

You can mix & match functions, wrap them up into an Postgres Function, then call them as an RPC (https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/rpc)